when add system call in xv6, Implicit Declaration error
I implement clone, join system call in sysproc.c.

int 
sys_clone(void)
{
    void (*fcn)(void*, void*);
    void *arg1, *arg2, *stack;

    if (argptr(0, (void*)&fcn, sizeof(fcn)) < 0 ||
        argptr(1, (void*)&arg1, sizeof(arg1)) < 0 ||
        argptr(2, (void*)&arg2, sizeof(arg2)) < 0 ||
        argptr(3, (void*)&stack, sizeof(stack)) < 0)
        return -1;

    return clone(fcn, arg1, arg2, stack);
}

int 
sys_join(void)
{
    void **stack;

    if (argptr(0, (void*)&stack, sizeof(stack)) < 0)
        return -1;

    return join(&stack);
}

and make clone, join function in proc.c.
int
clone(void(*fcn)(void *, void *), void *arg1, void *arg2, void *stack)
{
    int tid;
    struct proc *np;
    struct proc *curproc = myproc();

    if((np = allocproc()) == 0)
        return -1;

    np->pgdir = curproc->pgdir;
    np->sz = curproc->sz;
    np->parent = curproc;
    *np->tf = *curproc->tf;

    np->tf->esp = (uint)stack + 4096;
    np->tf->eip = (uint)fcn;
    np->tf->edx = (uint)arg1;
    np->tf->ecx = (uint)arg2;

    np->tf->eax = 0;

    acquire(&ptable.lock);
    np->state = RUNNABLE;
    tid = np->pid;
    release(&ptable.lock);

    return tid;
}

int
join(void **stack)
{
    struct proc *p;
    int havekids, pid;
    struct proc *curproc = myproc();

    acquire(&ptable.lock);
    for(;;){
        havekids = 0;
        for(p = ptable.proc; p < &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++){
            if(p->parent != curproc)
                continue;
            havekids = 1;
            if(p->state == ZOMBIE){
                pid = p->pid;
                kfree(p->kstack);
                p->kstack = 0;
                p->state = UNUSED;
                p->parent = 0;
                p->name[0] = 0;
                *stack = (void *)p->tf->esp;
                release(&ptable.lock);
                return pid;
            }
        }

        if(!havekids || curproc->killed){
            release(&ptable.lock);
            return -1;
        }

        sleep(curproc, &ptable.lock);
    }
}

and declare them in syscall.h, ,syscall.c, usys.S, user.h.
I tried to test clone and join by test.c.
So in virtualbox ubuntu 20.04.6 xv6, I wrote 'make qemu'.
But what i got is
sysproc.c: In function ‘sys_clone’:
sysproc.c:105:12: error: implicit declaration of function ‘clone’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  105 |     return clone(fcn, arg1, arg2, stack);
      |            ^~~~~
sysproc.c: In function ‘sys_join’:
sysproc.c:116:12: error: implicit declaration of function ‘join’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  116 |     return join(&stack);
      |            ^~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [<내장>: sysproc.o] 오류 1

I declared clone and join in sysproc.c and proc.c.

You need to declare them in defs.h as well.
